# Do not run function until condition is met

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have 2 values

```
var maxValues;
var incrementValues;
```

and I have a function.

```
runFunction();
```

the values increment based on ajax successes.

How do I keep checking whether maxValues is equal to incrementValues and once they are equal THEN run `runFunction()`.

Comment: Any chance we can see the code with the ajax call?

Comment: I have several ajax calls.  They work fine but they are all independent.

Comment: Do you want `runFunction()` to be called after all ajax calls have completed, or only if they all have completed and none have failed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the *check* in the `success` callback of your ajax request(s).

This is better than using an interval.

```
var check = function (maxValues, incrementValues) {
    if (maxValues == incrementValues) {
        runFunction();
    }
};

$.get( "example.php", function(data) {
    // Ajax successful
    check(data.maxValues, data.incrementValues);
});
```

Or as @TedHopp suggested, use the `always` callback:

```
$.get( "example.php", function() {
    // Ajax successful

}).always(function() {
    // success or no success, just "always"
    check(maxValues, incrementValues);
});
```

Check the [jQuery API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) for further information.

**If you don't want to add it to every ajax request**, you can build a custom Ajax function which implicitly calls your checks, see this answer for assistance: [jQuery AJAX custom function and custom callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821142/jquery-ajax-custom-function-and-custom-callback) .

Comment: HI Dan.  I have several ajax calls.  What I'm trying to do is run it just once, after all ajax requests are completed.

Comment: Then run check after every ajax success call.

Comment: @vjdhama - And after every ajax failure call as well, since the ajax call is complete whether it succeeds or fails.

Comment: @TedHopp He said "values increment based on ajax successes". Read the question.

Comment: @KingKongFrog - if you want to run the function only once after all ajax calls are complete, you can use `$(document).ajaxStop(function (){ ... })`  http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

Comment: @vjdhama - He also said "after all ajax requests are completed." Read the comment. :)

Comment: It's not clear, yet there are many possibilities for every case given :-)

Comment: @TedHopp i guess there is no use debating contradictory statements. Only KingKongFrog can clarify. But i think it would make sense incrementing on ajax successes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple, out-of-box solution that saves you a few lines of code, I have a tiny library dedicated for this purpose (run a callback when all given conditions are met) here: https://github.com/Zodiase/setrace.

I know the accepted answer already explains what should be done. But why write that *check* every time when you can use an one-liner provided by a super lightweight library?

Here's how:

```js
// Define the list of names for the conditions.
var conditions = [
  'downloaded_a',
  'downloaded_b',
  'timeout'
];

// Define what needs to run when all conditions are met.
var runAtTheEnd = () => {
  alert('All conditions met!');
};

// Create the race.
var race = SETRACE(conditions, runAtTheEnd);

$.get('http://i.imgur.com/y8bqp8t.png', race.set['downloaded_a']);

$.get('http://i.imgur.com/bDp49NE.png', race.set['downloaded_b']);

window.setTimeout(race.set['timeout'], 3000);

// Now when all three conditions are met, `runAtTheEnd` will be called.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Zodiase/setrace/v1.0.1/setrace.js"></script>
```