# Set session var with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I want to create a `session var`. I have a web page with some tabs that don't recharge when I active one another. So, I don't know how to set my session var.

Indeed, my first tab will generate the session var when the user submit the form into this tab. I'm trying to do it with ajax. So in my ajax file, I have this to set my var :

```
if(pg_num_rows($res) == 1)
 {                                  
    $flag=false;
    $message = "L'identifiant de l'essai existe déjà dans la base";
    array_push($tab_erreur,$cpt,$message);
  }else {
    $sessionIDEssai=$ligne[1]; //Here is my session var
  }
```

After, I want to return that value with an other like this :

```
echo json_encode($tab_erreur),$sessionIDEssai;
```

First of all I don't know if it's correct, because I can't get it in my callback function.

```
 function insert_essai_callback(responseObject,ioArgs) .
 {
    var jsonobject = eval(responseObject);
    console.log(jsonobject);
 }
```

I can get the first var `$tab_erreur`.

And after I don't know how to set my session var for all my tabs. I think that at the return of the ajax, I will get the value and I could set it and use it, but I'm not sure.

**EDIT**

I send an array in my ajax request like that :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit_button_essai').click(function(){

            $.post("ajax_insert_essai.php",{arr:data_essai}, insert_essai_callback,'json'); 
        });
    });
```

Comment: You don't seem to be reading any $_POST?

Comment: @N000b101 I'm reading a value of a row from an array. The array that I pass in my ajax request. I'll edit my post with that.

Comment: @N000b101 I don't get why I need to use $_POST. For now, I want to get a second value from my ajax.

Comment: How's your ajax setup? Does it perform a GET or a POST?

Comment: You have to send back to javascript an object (one object) containing all you need.

Comment: I did, The only thing that I found is insert my var into my array and get it after. That's not really clean, but it works. Thank you @kmsdev.

Comment: Don't use $.post(), use a standard jQuery Ajax setup, like in my example. It is much easier to control.

Comment: $.post("ajax_insert_essai.php",{arr:data_essai}, insert_essai_callback,'json'), either I am missing something or, but, inser_essai_callback, will NOT fire.

Comment: @Lison, for custom callbacks see this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821142/jquery-ajax-custom-function-and-custom-callback

Answer (score 0):

**Ajax**

```
 $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : './session.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        success : function(data){},
        error : function(){}
 });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['data']=$_POST['data'];
    echo $_SESSION['data'];
    ?> 
});
```

Data is what you send through a POST, now echo can return that data or a different amount of data to your Ajax request as a response.

Using, $.post():

```
$.post({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success,
    dataType: dataType
});
```

However, $.ajax(), is much much better, since you have more control over the flow, and if success do this etc.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not what I expect. I return an array from my ajax. But I want to return a second var. So first I return that : `echo json_encode($tab_erreur);` but how can I return something else and get it in my callback ?

Comment: `type : 'POST'` and then `$_GET['data']` ? Why? What is the `'data'` anyway? Please add some details and explain the code

Comment: You're still mixing HTTP Request Methods: `$_POST` and `$_GET`. You should either use one or another.

Comment: Hahahahahahahahahahahaha! I made a small mistake, and you think I am mixing these two. I am NOT mixing them. I am a quick responder to things, I am used to being active on Forums a lot over the years.