# New to ajax and can't set the session variable with a post request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I've been struggling with this for two hours now and I've narrowed down the issue to a simple test case. I've done plenty of research and finally settled on trying to reproduce the first answer from this question: [Set session var with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534942/set-session-var-with-ajax).

When I push this button (lazy html, but that's not where the issue lies):

```
<html>
<head>
...
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
...
<head>
<body>
....
<?php
    var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
<input type="button" class="update">
....
</body>
</html>
```

This ajax request in jquery.js gets called:

```
$.(".update").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"setSession.php",
        data: {bar: "foobar"},
        success: function() {
            console.log("Successful request sent");
        }
});
```

And finally the setSession.php file:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["foo"] = $_POST["bar"];
?>
```

The success message is printed to the console so I know I'm hitting the right file. Why isn't the session variable getting set? I have php 5.5.2 if that matters at all. Thanks for you help!

Comment: where are you calling ur js file or script ?

Comment: @Phoenix The ajax call is in jquery.js (just edited) and is called when I click the input button with the update class

Comment: how do you know it's not set when you are not even printing it

Comment: @TheFlash I dump the variable. So I'll click the button that sends the request and then reload the page.

Comment: do this:   `success: function() { location.reload(); }` to reload the page    **FYI:** the current page should also have `session_start();`

Comment: what does the `var_dump` output? You have not indicated on your sample script but on the page that has `var_dump($_SESSION);`, do you have `session_start();` at the top of the page?

Comment: @ConorBaumgart is ur button "submit" type ?

Comment: You need to write session_start() function on the php file where you are writing var_dump($_SESSION), only then you will be able to access that.

Answer (score 1):

Like I suggested on the comments, do this to fix your code:

Reload the page on your `success`:

```
success: function() {
            console.log("Successful request sent");  
            location.reload();
        }
```

Make sure you have `session_start()` in all the pages that uses sessions:

```
session_start(); //this must be at the top, before you print anything
```

Comment: This does not work. I actually get an error for starting a session after previously starting one.

Comment: Really? what does the error say? You should have one session_start() in a php page and it must be at the beggining of the page:  `<?php
    session_start();
?>`  Are you sure you did this? also change your `var_dump($_SESSION)` to `echo $_SESSION['foo'];` and see the results

Answer (score -1):

Might this can help you.

In `setSession.php` write `echo $_SESSION["foo"] = $_POST["bar"];`

In your ajax script do

```
$.(".update").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"setSession.php",
        data: {bar: "foobar"},
        success: function(e) {
            console.log(e);

        }
});
```

now open browser `console` (`F12`). click on your button.update. Check if is there written `bar` in console.